# Folders got randomly deleted

Tags: windows, dfs, file-server

I currently have a Windows Server 2012 R2 vm. This vm has a DFS share which is used as a file repository. It has been working flawlessly for about 4 years, however suddenly a bunch of random folders simply disappeared.

It appears that they were marked as deleted (can even be retrieved by software), however there are no audit records of the files ever being deleted by the four users having access to it. The event logs are also clean of any errors or warnings which relate to disks or dfs.

Anyone else experience this situation before?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `It appears that they were marked as deleted (can even be retrieved by software)` - What do you mean marked as deleted? They were deleted or they weren't. What do you mean they can be retrieved by software? What software? `however there are no audit records of the files ever being deleted` - Do toy have auditing enabled and configured?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Yes they were deleted and I managed to recover them by using data recovery software. And yes i do have auditing configured. Could bad sectors on a drive be responsible?